# Can I store a function including multiple variable in cellfun, which still can be used individually?

Tags: matlab

Im new to matlab, is it able to store function including multiple variable which still can be used?
Is it able to have the same result as below?

```
%example
f=sin(x*t+theta);   % function I used
x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];   % spactial distribution  % will remain unchange in for loop
t=[1 2 3 4 5];     % time
theta=[1 2 3 4 5];     % phase change by time (will be same length as time)
  first, I would like to do something to this function to made it :
F=[ sin(x*t+1) sin(x*t+2) sin(x*t+3) sin(x*t+4) sin(x*t+5)];
```

so I can call the function ,for example: F{1}=sin(x*t+1)
next, the function in F need to move together by time :

```
for b=1:length(theta)     % F{1},F{2},F{3},F{4},F{5}
    for a=1:length(t)    % time change
        A=F{b}(a);      % (a) is suppose to be the time change, but I don't know how to do with it
    end
end
```

The wave function will times a step function in my code at last, so I cant change the order of my code, it need to be step by step like that.
The length of t and theta will be greater then 1000, so I can't type the function one by one.

Comment: So your function is `sin(x*t+theta)`. You don’t need an array for that. Look up “anonymous function”. They can have multiple inputs!

Comment: What is `A`? Is this supposed to be a matrix with all the computed results? Or will you do something with it right there inside the loop?

Comment: @CrisLuengo `A` would be the output, I'm going to plot it.

Comment: I think you want to do `f=@(x,t,theta) sin(x*t+theta)`, and then call `f(x,t(a),theta(b))` inside your loop. You can vectorize the whole thing, you don't really need loops at all, but it's not important. What you need to do is pre-allocate `A`, then in the loop asking into it: `A(a,b) = f(...)`.